# query_posts does not return old posts?

Tags: wordpress

I'm using query_posts on my home page to fetch articles from multiple post types. I'm using following code to do so.

```
<?php query_posts( array('post_type' => array('post','page','custom_post1','custom_post2','custom_post3','custom_post4','custom_post5','custom_post6'))); 
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); // begin the Loop ?>
/*html code goes here*/
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

It fetches the posts rightly, but the problem is: it does not fetch old posts. So for example I have 1 post and its publish date is `02/july/2012`, this post won't be displayed on my home page. But as soon as I update the date to `02/Aug/2012` it starts showing up on Home page.

So is there any code I can add in `query_posts` that will enable older posts to be fetched too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress by default fetch 10 posts or number of posts set by user from admin.

query_posts accept argument that return number of record.

```
query_posts( 'posts_per_page=5' );
query_posts( 'posts_per_page=50' );
```

Comment: **Waow! LOL How Stupid of me. Thanks a lot @Muhammad Yasin**